Text Overflows The Footer
Here as you can see the texts are overflowing the footer, I have no problem with the header. I tried setting footer height but it didn't work.
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.78in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For custom headers and footers
\usepackage{multirow} % For multi-row cells in tables
\usepackage{xcolor} % For color definitions
\usepackage{circuitikz} % For circuit diagrams
\usepackage[mode=math]{siunitx} % For typesetting units
\usepackage{tikz} % For drawing diagrams
\usepackage{fontspec} % For specifying fonts
\usepackage[fontsize=11pt]{scrextend} % For adjusting font size
\usepackage{lipsum} % For generating dummy text
\usepackage{anyfontsize} % For specifying any font size

\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{24,44,77}

\newcolumntype{B}{>{\bfseries}l} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\newcommand\eighteen{\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand\fourteen{\fontsize{14pt}{17pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand\twelve{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand\eleven{\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont}

\fancypagestyle{page}{
    \fancyhf{} % Clear header and footer
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header rule
    % Header
    \fancyhead[L]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \eleven
            \coordinate (boxBottomLeft) at ($(current page.north west) + (0.78in,-0.2in)$);
            \coordinate (boxTopRight) at ($(current page.north west) + (3.93in,0)$);
            \draw [fill=blue,draw=blue] (boxBottomLeft) rectangle (boxTopRight);
            \coordinate (nodePosition) at ($(boxBottomLeft) + (-0.15in,-.3in)$);
            % Header content
            \node[below right, text=blue, text width=5in] at (nodePosition) {
             \begin{tabular}{l @{ : } l}
                Title of the Homework &  \\[-1em]
                Student Name & 
            \end{tabular}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    % Footer
    \fancyfoot[L]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \coordinate (boxBottomLeft) at ($(current page.south west) + (0.78in,0)$);
            \coordinate (boxTopRight) at ($(current page.south west) + (3.93in,0.05in)$);
            \draw [fill=blue,draw=blue] (boxBottomLeft) rectangle (boxTopRight);
            \coordinate (footTextStart) at ($(boxBottomLeft) + (-0.05in,0.6in)$);
            % Footer content
            \node[below right, text=blue] at (footTextStart) {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10.5}{\twelve{\textbf{ISTANBUL TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY}}}};
            \coordinate (page) at ($(boxBottomLeft) + (6.6in,0.2in)$);
            \node[above right, text=blue] at (page) {\eleven{\thepage}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.7in}

% Apply custom page style
\pagestyle{page}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document} 


You need to give some space for the footer and the header. I suggest to use top and bottom to make your intentions clear.
I changed to centimeters, as 0.78 inches is essentially the same as 2 centimeters.
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  top=3cm,
  bottom=3cm,
  left=2cm,
  right=2cm,
  headheight=13.6pt,
  showframe
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For custom headers and footers
\usepackage{multirow} % For multi-row cells in tables
\usepackage{xcolor} % For color definitions
\usepackage{circuitikz} % For circuit diagrams
\usepackage[mode=math]{siunitx} % For typesetting units
\usepackage{tikz} % For drawing diagrams
\usepackage{fontspec} % For specifying fonts
\usepackage[fontsize=11pt]{scrextend} % For adjusting font size
\usepackage{lipsum} % For generating dummy text
\usepackage{anyfontsize} % For specifying any font size

\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{24,44,77}

\newcolumntype{B}{>{\bfseries}l} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\newcommand\eighteen{\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand\fourteen{\fontsize{14pt}{17pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand\twelve{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand\eleven{\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont}

\fancypagestyle{page}{%
    \fancyhf{}% Clear header and footer
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
    % Header
    \fancyhead[L]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \eleven
            \coordinate (boxBottomLeft) at ($(current page.north west) + (0.78in,-0.2in)$);
            \coordinate (boxTopRight) at ($(current page.north west) + (3.93in,0)$);
            \draw [fill=blue,draw=blue] (boxBottomLeft) rectangle (boxTopRight);
            \coordinate (nodePosition) at ($(boxBottomLeft) + (-0.15in,-.3in)$);
            % Header content
            \node[below right, text=blue, text width=5in] at (nodePosition) {
             \begin{tabular}{l @{ : } l}
                Title of the Homework &  \\[-1em]
                Student Name & 
            \end{tabular}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
    % Footer
    \fancyfoot[L]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \coordinate (boxBottomLeft) at ($(current page.south west) + (0.78in,0)$);
            \coordinate (boxTopRight) at ($(current page.south west) + (3.93in,0.05in)$);
            \draw [fill=blue,draw=blue] (boxBottomLeft) rectangle (boxTopRight);
            \coordinate (footTextStart) at ($(boxBottomLeft) + (-0.05in,0.6in)$);
            % Footer content
            \node[below right, text=blue] at (footTextStart) {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10.5}{\twelve{\textbf{ISTANBUL TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY}}}};
            \coordinate (page) at ($(boxBottomLeft) + (6.6in,0.2in)$);
            \node[above right, text=blue] at (page) {\eleven{\thepage}};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}

\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{Arial}

% Apply custom page style
\pagestyle{page}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document} 

Remove the showframe option when satisfied by your experiments. I also added a few % to hide endlines that you forgot.


Thank you for your return, also may I ask what is the use of the % at the end? I am kinda new

@BarbarosTeomanKosoglu see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat

Use something like:
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.78in, footskip=1.2cm, includefoot]{geometry}


